# How to make function execute only once in JS / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a structure like this :

```
// App.js
var APP = {
    viewIndex: function(){
        EVT.doSomething();
    },

    // Another function below
}

// Event.js

var EVT = {
    doSomething: function(){
        deleteField();

        function deleteField(){
            $("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){
                console.log("Clicked");
            })
        }
    }
}
```

my project is SPA wannabe, so when i want to change the page, it must execute some function inside `App.js`, but my problem is, when i call `APP.viewIndex()` `(when i go to Index, go back, and go to index again(without refreshing page) )`, the function inside `EVT -> doSomething()` is execute twice, so i have no idea how to prevent it,

in my console i got this :

> Clicked
>
> Clicked

*sorry if my explanation is a bit complicated

hope you guys can help me out of this problem :D

thanks

Comment: See documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: @MUT so how to implement in my function ??

Comment: @MuhammadBimaPramadinata -- Use `$("#btn").one( ... )`.

Comment: Try this. `$('#your-btn-id').one('click',function({
//do something
}))`

Answer (score 0):

Use a property to remember if you already called `deleteField()`.

```
var EVT = {
    didSomething: false,
    doSomething: function(){
        if (!this.didSomething) {
            deleteField();
            this.didSomething = true;
        }
        function deleteField(){
            $("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){
                console.log("Clicked");
            })
        }
    }
}
```